# Why does child proccess has to go first in piping ls and more commands in C?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
        perror("execlp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("more", "more", "-3", NULL);
        perror("execlp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I dont understand, why does my program when we say `if (pid == 0)` works like intended where more program display 3 lines and that again 3 lines after the space and so on, and when i say `if (pid!=0)` `ls` display everything and `more` command doesnt work? Why is this?

Why does it matter if parent process does `ls` and child `more` command or parent does `more` and child `ls`? Either way more wont print anything until ls writes data into the pipe.

Here is the code i tried versus the one above, i tried having parent process calling "ls" command and child process call "more" command. I don't see why this would be an issue? I just changed "responsobilities", i don't see how this changes anything? child process with "more" command comes first, it will attempt to read pipe and it will block since it's empty, parent process with "ls" command will eventually write into the pipe and the child process with "more" will get unblocked, read from the pipe and print it out on the user screen. So i don't understand why is it only displaying the contents of the directory, instead of showing me three piece's of content and then after i click space another three, and so on..

```
    if (pid != 0) {
       dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
       close(fd[0]);
       close(fd[1]);
       execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
       perror("execlp");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
       dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
       close(fd[0]);
       close(fd[1]);
       execlp("more", "more", "-3", NULL);
       perror("execlp");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: If you use `if (pid != 0)` you reverse the logic and must reverse the code inside as well. So with `if (pid != 0)` then you must do the `more` part of the pipe inside that `if`, and the `ls` part of the pipe in the `else` case.

Comment: But why is that neccessery? Why does it matter if child does more or ls command and if parent does more or ls command? One writes to pipe, other reads from it. If more starts first and tries to read from pipe it will block until ls writes something to it. Or am i missing something?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. Please create a [mre] of the *failing* program and [edit] your question to show it. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The order of the processes doesn't matter. What matters is that you connect them to the proper ends of the pipe. `ls` has to have its `stdout` connected to the write end, and `more` has to have its `stdin` connected to the read end. So you have to interchange `fd[0]` and `fd[1]` if you change which program is run.

Comment: But i've already done that in the code, all i changed is if(fork() != 0) and the program behaves totally different. ls standard input is still connected to pipe[1] and more standard output on the pipe[0];

Comment: Please, again, show us the ***failing*** program. Letting us see code that works doesn't help us much.

Comment: The thing is i cannot show you any errors since i dont get them, all i get is more not working with ls as intentended. All i get is ls displaying contents of my folder and that's it. Should i include some screenshots maybe or?

Comment: Well that program where `more` is not working is the program we want to see. If it's not possible to copy-paste input/output (like in your case) a detailed description of the actual versus desired behavior is enough. But the important part is that we see an actual [mre] that replicates the problem you have.

Comment: I've added update, please take a look now and if you can shed some light on this, im really lost about this one.

Comment: Try to synchronize parent and child process before `exec`ing. e.g. use a mutex/semaphore/flock

Comment: I've tried that as well, i've tried sleep variations as well but nothing seems to be working. I dont understand why is the behavior different because of one trivial change that shouldnt change anything at all about the code.

Comment: I also see misbehavior with the version of the program in which `more` runs in the child, but not *the same* misbehavior.  I get exactly three lines of `ls` output, then `more` apparently terminates without displaying anything further -- no prompt and no additional `ls` output.  I suspect that this has to do with the behavior of the grandparent (a shell) when the parent terminates.